# h3 tag doesnt echo in foreach loop in php

Tags: php

```
function news5($newsarray) {
    $str = '';
    foreach($newsarray as $value) {
    $str.= '<h3>$value['title']</h3>';}
    return $str;
}
echo news5($newsarray);
```

$newsarray is a two - dimensional array, i want to display first value of every subarray in h3 but it doesnt work, without h3 tag everything is fine, but i want it in h3. pls help!

It says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'title' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\news\news.php on line 7"

Comment: i forgot to say im trying it on localhost!

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Try $str.= '<h3>'.$value['title'].'</h3>'

Comment: Whats up with the serial downvoting? Mr Moderator?

Comment: Seems like someone has mixed up- and downvoting :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```
function news5($newsarray) {
    $str = '';
    foreach($newsarray as $value)
 {
    $str.= "<h3>".$value['title']."</h3>"; 
}
    return $str;
}
echo news5($newsarray);
```

Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with these conversions made. If you require all input substrings that have associated named entities to be translated, use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead.

Answer (score 5):

#### Why it doesn't work

```
$str.= '<h3>$value['title']</h3>';
```

Strings wrapped in single quotes don't evaluate variable references, as explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php); you're also not properly opening and closing the single quotes, causing a parse error; double quotes or [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) would solve that, but you also need to keep in mind that values must be properly escaped to be used in HTML.

#### What works

```
$str .= '<h3>' . htmlspecialchars($value['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</h3>';
```

See also: [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: @lord_sommersby I can't stress the importance of escaping enough; preventing XSS is important.

Answer (score -2):

You are ending your string with an unescaped single quote. So your string just is

```
'<h3>$value['
```

And then the plain `title` appears. That is causing the `unexpected {string}`. You would either have to escape your quotes

```
'<h3>$value[\'title\']</h3>'
```

or use different (double) quotes in *one part* of your statement - either the array key or the surrounding quotes.

Another problem you will be facing: Variables in single quotes don't evaluate. So your echoed result will be:

```
$value['title']
```

which is not what you want (you want the content of that array):

```
$str .= "<h3>{$value['title']}</h3>";
```

where the `{}` are optional.

Comment: I'd really like to hear the reasons for the downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

```
$str .= '<h3>';
$str .= $value['title'];
$str .= '</h3>';
```